# Jquery unexpected "scale" behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have the following:

Many anchors that have a display: block; css property, and the following two functions attached to two buttons:

```
function ZoomIn() {
    $("#MainContent_inside_panel a").hide();
    $("#MainContent_inside_panel a").effect("scale", { percent: 200 }, 1000);
    $("#MainContent_inside_panel a").show();
}

function ZoomOut() {
    $("#MainContent_inside_panel a").hide();
    $("#MainContent_inside_panel a").effect("scale", { percent: -200 }, 1000);
    $("#MainContent_inside_panel a").show();
```

If I only click the button that calls ZoomIn, it works (well, it doesn't hide everything, but that's not that big of a deal). If I click zoomin, then zoomout or zoomout, then zoomin, it breaks.  3/4 of the blocks will resize, but the others get weirdly (and inconsistently small).  In firefox, I see the weirdly small anchors - in chrome they just disappear.

After it "breaks", clicking either button does nothing.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Edit: HTML (just a bunch of these repeated):

```
<a id="MainContent_1_0" class="unused"></a>
<a id="MainContent_400001393" class="used"></a>
<a id="MainContent_1_2" class="unused"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.inside_panel a 
{
display: block;
float: left;
width: 7px;
height: 7px;
margin: 2px;
padding: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

a.used 
{
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the Javascript console for errors?

Comment: @George Yeah, no errors or warnings. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Can you post the relevant markup?

Comment: Your HTML IDs do not match any of the elements referenced in the Javascript.

Comment: @George My apologies, I should have been clearer.  All of the anchors are inside a div with id `#MainContent_inside_panel`.  The jquery inheritance selector grabs any "a" element that is inside a div with id `MainContent_inside_panel`, which in this case, is all my block a's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use negative values when shrinking the object.

If you wish to shrink the object to the previous size after it was scaled by 200% - set it to 50%.

```
$("#MainContent_inside_panel a").effect("scale", { percent: 50 }, 1000);
```

Simple math: if object is size of 100px, then scaling it by 200% would make it 200px. To make the object 100px again you should cut it in half, that is 50%.

Comment: ... Wow.  It seem the example I followed was incorrect.  It never occurred to me to try this, as I'm quite new to jquery and just assumed the author new what they were talking about.  Huh.  Thanks.